# How to batch export rasters as GeoTIFF with new CRS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export, extents, ppygis

I need some help concerning the exporting of a large batch of raster-files (mostly SID-types) as GeoTIFFs in a reference system (WGS 84) that is different from the one in which the original files were georeferenced (Belgian Lambert 1972).

I didn't want to export the files one at a time, as I have over 2000 different files to go through. For that reason, I attempted to use my little knowledge on Python to come up with a script in QGIS that could automatically export a large batch of raster-files (see below).

This code worked fine at first, but afterwards I discovered in ArcGIS that the extent of my GeoTIFFs was still given in meters instead of degrees, even though the reference system in the properties clearly states WGS84 (see image). Can any of you tell me how I should adapt my code so that the extent is converted as well?

[image]

```
#Directory where the exports have to end up in
myDir = '//fsarchive/INBO_historische_kaarten/_EXPORT_/'

#Reference System that I want the exported tiffs to have
trs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
trs.createFromId(4326)

layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()

#for every layer in the layer interface
for index, layer in enumerate(layers):
    name = layer.name()
    extent = layer.extent()
    width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
    renderer = layer.renderer()
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    pipe.set(provider.clone())
    pipe.set(renderer.clone())

    print (index + 1)   #these prints are just to follow the progress when the script is running
    print ("of")
    print (len(layers))
    print (name)

    opts = ["COMPRESS=ZIP"] #compress the GeoTIFF with the ZIP-method

    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter (myDir + name + ".tif")
    file_writer.setCreateOptions(opts)
    file_writer.writeRaster (pipe, width, height, extent, trs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question here, as I finally found a solution.
So instead of writing a python script, I used a script based on the gdal warp tool.

It worked for me, but you might want to change some of the parameters, according to what your intentions are with the files.

```
# To run in qgis (3.0) python console (plugins -> python console)

# first import the QGIS processing module:
import processing
import os # to search directories

indir = 'folder/original/files'
# I made this test folder, you can delete it
outdir = 'folder/for/output/exports' 

# list all files
for file in os.listdir(indir):
   if file.endswith(".sid"):
       infile = os.path.join(indir, file)
       print(infile)
       outfile = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'.tif')
       print(outfile)

       # transform (reproject) raster with GDALwarp (= raster -> projections -> warp)
       processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", 
       {'INPUT':infile, 'SOURCE_CRS':'EPSG:31370','TARGET_CRS':'EPSG:4326','NODATA':255,'TARGET_RESOLUTION':0,'OPTIONS':'','RESAMPLING':0,'DATA_TYPE':5, 'TARGET_EXTENT' : '', 'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS' : 'EPSG:4326','MULTITHREADING':False, 'OUTPUT':outfile})
```