# QGIS - Batch export of WMS into .tif

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, geotiff-tiff, batch

I'm trying to export several areas delineated with a Shapefile.

My Shapefile has different "id" and, for each id I want to export a raster (.tif) from a WMS layer (displayed with the plugin QuickMapServices).
The idea is, as for the Atlas, being able to export as many .tif as I have "id" in my shape. The export would follow the extent of the considered entity.

I visited many pages, and it seems that it's not possible. But I would like to ask, maybe a new method exists now.

My final goal is to have clipped raster following the delineation of my Shapefile (but for this I need .tif). And for this I can eventually run a batch.

For example, on the following image, I want to export 6 raster layers:

[image]

[Visited pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386218/qgis-exporting-saving-extents-of-wms-raster-layer-in-a-batch-process)
[Visited pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371586/batch-export-rasters-as-rendered-images)
[Visited pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374078/saving-rasters-as-in-batch-process)
[Visited pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341074/batch-tiff-export-qgis)
[Visited pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278344/how-to-batch-export-rasters-as-geotiff-with-new-crs)
[Visited pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440460/batch-saving-multiple-rendered-images-in-qgis)
[Visited pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208545/how-to-batch-export-raster-files-from-qgis)

Comment: what have you actually tried? what is not working? What you describe sounds perfectly possible using the atlas function

Comment: The Atlas is exporting layouts. I need to export raster layers to clip them.

Comment: I searched plugins or solutions using python (which I do not know). Tried exporting manually, but this would take a lot of time and I would need to create as many Shapefile as I have entities to set properly the extent of the export. I tried to export the whole area into .tif, but I received an error after 30 mins (it is extremely long, something like 60 hours).

Comment: Your explanations are exactly what I was searching for. I'm using Atlas frequently and never though of exporting .tif from it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** use Atlas:

- I usually create a square grid
- Create a new layout. Square page size, for example 1000*1000 mm.
- Enable Atlas. Grid as coverage layer, a few % margin, Image export format tif

[image]

[image]

Then you can combine the rasters to one [virtual raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html?highlight=build%20virtual%20raster#build-virtual-raster) to make clipping it easier.

Comment: BERA: Could you please rapidly explain what this solves in the workflow, and what the resulting workflow is? I understand that there's something I don't understand, but I can't figure out what !